# Rolling Non Circular Objects Matter.js

Tags: javascript, physics-engine, matter.js

I am pretty new to Matter.js so forgive me if the answer to this is obvious.

I am trying to rotate a body on top of another (static) body and have it roll along that surface.

I need something similar to the car demo but I need there to be zero acceleration to the roll. i.e. every iteration of the loop I should be able to set a rotation amount and have the body rotate that much.
I also need this to able to work with non-eliptical bodies.

I have some code that rotates the body as I would like but I am struggling to make the body roll along the surface based on its rotation.

Any help would be much appreciated. Please see my current code below.

```js
// module aliases
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Body = Matter.Body;

// create an engine
var engine = Engine.create();

// create a renderer
var render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine
});

var boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
var ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true });

// add all of the bodies to the world
World.add(engine.world, [boxA, ground]);

// run the renderer
Render.run(render);

engine.world.gravity = {x: 0, y:0, scale: 0}; //disable gravity

window.setInterval(function () {
  Body.rotate(boxA, 0.01);
  Body.translate(boxA, { x: 0, y: 10 });
  
  Engine.update(engine, 1000 / 60);
}, 1000 / 60)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.17.1/matter.min.js"></script>
```